# How to remove each note on dblclick and also remove from the array with filter method

Tags: javascript

I need help to remove each note on dblclick and also remove from the notes array with filter method. We should use unique id with Math.random()

Here is my code

```
let notes = [];
const container = document.querySelector('.flex-cont')
const inputNote = document.getElementById('noteInput')
const addButton = document.getElementById('addNote')
let noteElement;


class Note {
  constructor(description, id) {
    this.description = description
    this.id = id
  }
}

addButton.addEventListener('click', postNote)

function postNote() {
  let note = inputNote.value
  let newNote = new Note(note, Math.random())
  noteElement = document.createElement('div')
  noteElement.classList.add('paper', 'pink')
  noteElement.setAttribute('id', this.id)
  let noteText = document.createElement('p')
  noteText.textContent = note
  noteElement.append(noteText)
  let tape = document.createElement('div')
  tape.classList.add('tape-section')
  noteElement.append(tape)
  noteElement.addEventListener('dblclick', () => {
    // notes.filter(id => this.id != id )
    // if (noteElement.id === this.id) {
      const doDelete = confirm('Are you sure ?');
      if (doDelete) {
        noteElement.remove()
      }
    // }
    
  })
  container.appendChild(noteElement)
  notes.push(newNote) 
  inputNote.value = '';
}

console.log(notes)
```

HTML and CSS are here

http://jsfiddle.net/30tjop4d/

Comment: Have you tried this: `notes = notes.filter(n => n.id !== newNote.id);`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let notes = [];
const container = document.querySelector('.flex-cont')
const inputNote = document.getElementById('noteInput')
const addButton = document.getElementById('addNote')


class Note {
  constructor(description, id, element) {
    this.description = description
    this.id = id
    this.element = element
  }
}

addButton.addEventListener('click', postNote)

function postNote() {
  let note = inputNote.value
  noteElement = document.createElement('div')
  noteElement.classList.add('paper', 'pink')
  noteElement.setAttribute('id', this.id)
  let noteText = document.createElement('p')
  noteText.textContent = note
  noteElement.append(noteText)
  let tape = document.createElement('div')
  tape.classList.add('tape-section')
  noteElement.append(tape)
  
  let newNote = new Note(note, Math.random(), noteElement)
  notes.push(newNote) 
  
  noteElement.addEventListener('dblclick', () => {
    // notes.filter(id => this.id != id )
    // if (noteElement.id === this.id) {
      const doDelete = confirm('Are you sure ?')
      if (doDelete) {
        const noteToRemove = notes.find(n => n.id === newNote.id)
        noteToRemove.element.remove()
        notes = notes.filter(n => n.id !== newNote.id)
        console.log(notes.map(n => n.id))
      }
    // }
    
  })
  
  container.appendChild(noteElement)
  inputNote.value = '';
}

console.log(notes)
```

```css
:root {
  --pink: #ecb2ba;
  --pink-dark: #c6939a;
  --tape-gray: #dbd8be;
  --tape-edge-gray: #b7b49d;
  --transparent: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #1a2980;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.flex-cont {
  padding: 30px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 30px;
}

input,
button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2em auto;
  padding: 0.5em 0.7em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  /* width: 15em; */
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em 0.25em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
:root {
  --pink: #ecb2ba;
  --pink-dark: #c6939a;
  --tape-gray: #dbd8be;
  --tape-edge-gray: #b7b49d;
  --transparent: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.pink {
  --paper-color: var(--pink);
  --paper-dark: var(--pink-dark);
  --shadow-size: 1px;
  --transparent: rgba(236, 178, 186, 0);
}

.blue {
  --paper-color: #d5e0f9;
  --paper-dark: #c2d0ea;
  --shadow-size: 3px;
  --transparent: rgba(213, 224, 249, 0);
}

.paper {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(
      to bottom right,
      var(--paper-dark),
      20%,
      var(--transparent)
    ),
    var(--paper-color);
  min-width: 250px;
  min-height: 130px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Caveat", cursive;
  font-size: 2rem;
  box-shadow: var(--shadow-size) var(--shadow-size) 2px var(--paper-dark);
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.paper::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(
      var(--transparent),
      50%,
      var(--paper-dark),
      51%,
      var(--transparent)
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      to right,
      var(--transparent),
      50%,
      var(--paper-dark),
      51%,
      var(--transparent)
    );
}

.tape-section {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.top-tape {
  position: absolute;
  height: 4vmin;
  top: -5px;
  width: 110%;
  background-color: var(--tape-gray);
  border-right: 1px dotted var(--tape-edge-gray);
  border-left: 1px dotted var(--tape-edge-gray);
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.tape-section:first-of-type {
  top: 0;
}

.tape-section:last-of-type {
  bottom: 0;
}

.tape-section::before,
.tape-section::after {
  content: "";
  width: 10vmin;
  height: 4vmin;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--tape-gray);
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-right: 1px dotted var(--tape-edge-gray);
  border-left: 1px dotted var(--tape-edge-gray);
}

.tape-section:last-of-type::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: -4vmin;
  top: -3vmin;
}

.tape-section:first-of-type::before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: -4vmin;
}

.tape-section:first-of-type::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  right: -4vmin;
  top: 0;
}

.tape-section:last-of-type::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: -4vmin;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Notes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Notes</h1>
    <input type="text" id="noteInput" placeholder="enter your note" />
    <button id="addNote">Add Note</button>
    <div class="flex-cont">
      <!-- <div class="paper pink">
        <p>drink more water</p>
        <div class="tape-section"></div>
      </div> -->
    </div>
    <!-- <script src="./countries-db.js"></script> -->
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: on point! tnx a lot :)